# Paddle objects are not moving (Python code)

Tags: python, oop, object

[image]
My first paddle was moving but when i created the second paddle it stopped moving. Here is my code in the main.py and paddle.py

[image]

Answer (score 0):

def up(self) and def down(self) are incorrectly indented. They need to be a part of the class.

class Paddle(Turtle):
def **init**(self, position):
...
def up(self):
...
def down(self):
...